Starting media3.DownloadService at 5AM in the background every day
we use media3 library to display video and play audio in our application to take a user through a workout routine step by step. We would like to give the user an option to predownload some of this media every morning (while their phone is charging and they have a network), so that the media is available regardless of their internet connection later in the day.
I have tried the following:

Create a CoroutineWorker that gets waken up every morning at 5AM by the alarm manager.
In the worker, use setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo), and then call DownloadService.sendAddDownload with the DownloadRequest for all media files.

However, that doesn't work, since API > 31 doesn't allow starting services from the background, since ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException gets thrown.
I have also tried the following:

Create a CoroutineWorker that gets waken up every morning at 5AM by the alarm manager.
In the worker, use setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo), and then call DownloadManager.addDownload directly to schedule the download.
However, this doesn't seem to work correctly either, and there every once in a while there is an ANR that is recorded in the FirebaseCrashlytics that originates from the worker, so I'm not convinced that that is a right approach either.

Any ideas how to approach this? Everything that I have found (in the documentation for media3 originates from user pressing the button in the app, but what are recommendations if we want to offer the user the ability to pre-cache all of their media for a smoother offline experience. Thank you !

Is there a reason you use alarm manager, not work manager? (This most probably won't solve your issue, tho, sorry)

I tried using periodic WorkManager, but it never triggered. It would work if the app was open, or even if the phone was awake. But at 5AM, it did not.
